# Shell Script - find command output sort based on time of file created

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have one linux server where i am getting lot of files (From one of client servers pushing 1000 files per sec to this server) , i need to download these files based on file created. 

1. need to avoid current writing files(-cmin +1)

2. Second thing i need to start file with time greater than last file downloaded. 

Find command seems to be is ok, but while sorting by modified time is not correct it seems.

**Example : my script**

```
var=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -r /home/DOWNLOADER/src/mon20170622_1_9.unl);touch --date "$var" /tmp/13;find /home/DOWNLOADER/src/ -newer /tmp/13  \! -cmin -1 -name "*.unl" -type f  -exec ls -ltr {} + | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'
```

Last Downloaded File :/home/DOWNLOADER/src/mon20170622_1_9.unl

Comment: Add an example of the output you are getting that is not sorting correctly.

Comment: `var=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -r  /home/DOWNLOADER/mon20161109_309_6048_1.unl);touch --date "$var" /tmp/13;find /home/DOWNLOADER/src/ -newer /tmp/13  \! -cmin -1 -name "*.unl" -type f  -exec ls -ltr {} + | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'`   **Result** mon20170622_1_9.unl 
mon20170622_1_2.unl 
mon20170622_1_10.unl 
mon20170622_1_50.unl
mon20170622_1_45.unl
**Actual Modified Date**
`date -r mon20170622_1_9.unl`
Thu Jun 22 09:10:22 IST 2017,
`date -r mon20170622_1_50.unl`,
Thu Jun 22 09:10:32 IST 2017
 `date -r mon20170622_1_45.unl`,
Thu Jun 22 09:10:31 IST 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -newer last_downloaded_file -cmin +1 -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" |sort
```